# `display: inline-block` causes horizontal space only in safari when zoomed in

Tags: html, css, safari

This is my html and css

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.no-white-spc {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.text {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 9px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="no-white-spc">
  <div class="row no-white-spc">
    <div class="text">
      Foo
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row no-white-spc">
    <div class="text">
      Bar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nothing unexpected here. The issue arrises when you view this in Safari and zoom in. At various zoom levels, you see random gaps appearing in between the two `.row`s

[image: screenshot of display:inline-block issue in safari browser]

Heres the same example with some js to display the box dimensions.

```js
const containerEl = document.querySelector("#container");
const texts = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
const debugEl = document.querySelector("#debug");

new ResizeObserver(() => {
  debugEl.textContent = `Container: ${containerEl.clientWidth}w X ${containerEl.clientHeight}h px`;
  texts.forEach(r => {
    r.textContent = `Row: ${r.clientWidth}w X ${r.clientHeight}h px`;
  })
}).observe(containerEl);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.no-white-spc {
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.text {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 9px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="no-white-spc">
  <div class="row no-white-spc">
    <div class="text">
      Foo World
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row no-white-spc">
    <div class="text">
      Bar World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<pre id="debug" style="color:black;"></pre>
```

The odd thing is that in Safari, the row heights (`30px + 30px`) do not add up to the container's height (`59px`). In Chrome and Firefox, the container's height is `60px` as expected.

This feels like a bug in Safari. It doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox. Does anyone know a work around to fix this given the constraints of using `display:inline-block` on the `.row`s